# Issue with unicode or hidden control marks in Word

Tags: unicode, ms-word

I've described problem in attached file with an exact example.

What's the difference between text 1 and 2 in attached file?!! which hidden control characters make text 1 numbering to be displayed like this?!! it's a part of my word document TOC (Chapter 4 part 2) and must be shown like text 2. Most part of TOC are shown correctly.

docx file is uploaded here:

http://www.fileswap.com/dl/pbsEvh1YI/
or
http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1379678521

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in right/left orientation.

Text 1: Paragraph is right-to-left and contains (in this order):

- "4-2-" in English language with left-to-right orientation, and then
- طراحی in "FA" language, inherits right-to-left orientation from paragraph.

Text 2: Paragraph is again right-to-left and language "FA" and contains:

- "4-2- طراحی" in right-to-left orientation.

Hint: Export file in html, it is visible in html source code.